# Load image from phone local storage of android react-native + expo

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, huawei-mobile-services

My code does not gives any error when executed over **expo** (react-native) but the image is also not loading. The path I get from details of the image in android is "Internal storage/DCIM/images.jpeg" therefore searching over forums read a suggestion to replace Internal storage with "file:///storage/emulated/0/". But this too does not work. The only output I get is the **Hello, world!**  text.My device is Huawei BG2-U01.

Hope I am not missing out on any basics.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View,Image } from 'react-native';

export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  
  render() {
  
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
         <Text>Hello, world!</Text>
   
        <Image source={{uri:'file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/images.jpeg'}} style={{width: 60, height: 60}} /> 
      
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set Width and Height for the source prop
Ex :

```
<Image source={{width:200,height:200,uri:'file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/images.jpeg'}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the network address path

   2. Establish the URL object
   3. Establish the URL link conn
   4. Set the link method of Conn.
   5. Get the input stream of Conn
   6. New a `byte[]arry`.
   7. Create a local file and get the output stream of the file.
   8. Write `byte[]to` file with `OutputStream`.
   9. Then `bitmapfactory.decodefile ()`, get the bitmap object and display it on the picture control.